# Mapbox Geocoding API V5- Get all neighborhoods in a city

Tags: geocoding, mapbox

Is there a way to get all neighborhoods per city by lat and lng from mapbox API V5.

For example, if I search using the lat and lng of Long Beach.
-118.1937, 33.7701

I expect to get back all the neighborhoods, instead, I only get back one result of 
"place_name: "Downtown, Long Beach, California 90802, United States""

I have changed the response limit and bound box, with no results.

Here is the mapbox playground.
https://www.mapbox.com/api-playground/#/forward-geocoding

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapbox doesn't really do neighborhoods, they require some sort of search data to pull either addresses or places.

However, there are services where you can get neighborhood data.  I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557720/where-can-i-find-a-city-neighborhood-database) to have several links (sadly, most of them outdated....), with [the reference to Zillow](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm) having a lot of promise.

I'd also suggest [the Census Bureau data](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/geocoder.html) as it may have what you are looking for, but it is what I would call 'less than user friendly' to find anything - unless you are comfortable reading government spec sort of things... :)

Comment: can you mark the answer as 'accepted'? (I'm new here as well and trying to get my reputation up there, too! :)